# Merge [htmlhelpers], [html-helper] into [htmlhelper]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

The current distribution is the following one:

- [htmlhelper](/questions/tagged/htmlhelper) (472)
- [htmlhelpers](/questions/tagged/htmlhelpers) (63)
- [html-helper](/questions/tagged/html-helper) (56)
- [html-helpers](/questions/tagged/html-helpers) (0)

I have not enough reputation to propose a synonym (silly requirement, isn't it?), so please merge.

Comment: I would prefer using [tag:html-helper], instead of [tag:htmlhelper]. Maybe the plural form makes more sense, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good idea -- I decided to merge into [html-helper](/questions/tagged/html-helper) in this case. We can pluralize later to taste.